# Can't initialize database from Azure App Service

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, sqlalchemy, azure-web-app-service

I have an application that works perfectly if i start it from visual studio. The application works and creates a database on Azure SQL Database. However if I distribute the application on App Service, the web application works, but as soon as I try to query the database it gives me an error.The error is:

**sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'users'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")**

However if I have previously created the database (for example by starting it locally first) everything works perfectly! So the problem is it doesn't want to create the database.
I connect to the database through:

```
server = "bookingserver.database.windows.net"
database = 'bookingdatabase'
username = 'server'
password = #pass here#
driver = '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'

odbc_str = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;UID='+username+';DATABASE='+ 
database + ';PWD='+ password
connect_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=' + urllib.parse.quote_plus(odbc_str)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = connect_str
_db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

And my tables like:

```
class Prenotation(_db.Model):
id = _db.Column(_db.Integer, primary_key=True)
hour= _db.Column(_db.String (30))
username = _db.Column(_db.String (30))
code = _db.Column(_db.Integer)

def __init__( self, hour, username, code):
   self.hour = hour
   self.username = username
   self.code = code
```

To initialize the database:

```
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  _db.create_all()
  app.run()
```

Comment: Did you installed **pyodbc** library and then imported it to before connecting to Azure Sql Database?

Comment: Yes, I did, I also added it to requirements.txt

Comment: I solved it by moving create_all just after declaring the modules!

Answer (score 0):

You can do some changes to the code.

do some initialize database change in this code.

old code

```java
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  _db.create_all()
  app.run()
```

new Code move _db.create_all() from this place.

```java
if __name__ == "__main__": 
  app.run()
```

Thanks to @luiss.black for your valuable suggestion to detect Can't initialize database from Azure App Service.